# How to add multiple ContentView(user controls) in the list view in xamarin.forms

Tags: listview, user-controls, xamarin.forms

I am having different user controls(ContentViews) and I want them all in the list view of xamarin.forms . Please help.

Comment: add what you have tried yet

Comment: add some screen shots or code that elaborates how you want .

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by using View Cells